# How do I download images from a server and then upload it to a website using R?

Tags: r, windows, web, server, cygwin

Okay, so I have approximately 2 GB worth of files (images and what not) stored on a server (I'm using Cygwin right now since I'm on Windows) and I was wondering if I was able to get all of this data into R and then eventually translate it onto a website where people can view/download those images?

I currently have installed the ssh package and have logged into my server using:

```
ssh::ssh_connect("name_and_server_ip_here")
```

I've been able to successfully connect, however, I am not particular sure how to locate the files on the server through R. I assume I would use something like scp_download to download the files from the server, but as mentioned before, I am not particularly sure how to locate the files from the server, so I  wouldn't be able to download them anyways (yet)!

Any sort of feedback and help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ssh::ssh_exec_internal` and some shell commands to "find" commands.

```r
sess <- ssh::ssh_connect("r2@myth", passwd="...")
out <- ssh::ssh_exec_internal(sess, command = "find /home/r2/* -maxdepth 3 -type f -iname '*.log'")
str(out)
# List of 3
#  $ status: int 0
#  $ stdout: raw [1:70] 2f 68 6f 6d ...
#  $ stderr: raw(0)
```

The stdout/stderr are raw (it's feasible that the remote command did not produce ascii data), so we can use `rawToChar` to convert. (This may not be console-safe if you have non-ascii data, but it is here, so I'll go with it.)

```r
rawToChar(out$stdout)
# [1] "/home/r2/logs/dns.log\n/home/r2/logs/ping.log\n/home/r2/logs/status.log\n"
remote_files <- strsplit(rawToChar(out$stdout), "\n")[[1]]
remote_files
# [1] "/home/r2/logs/dns.log"    "/home/r2/logs/ping.log"   "/home/r2/logs/status.log"
```

For downloading, `scp_download` is *not* vectorized, so we can only upload one file at a time.

```r
for (rf in remote_files) ssh::scp_download(sess, files = rf, to = ".")
#    4339331 C:\Users\r2\.../dns.log
#   36741490 C:\Users\r2\.../ping.log
#   17619010 C:\Users\r2\.../status.log
```

For uploading, `scp_upload` *is* vectorized, so we can send all in one shot. I'll create a new directory (just for this example, and to not completely clutter my remote server :-), and then upload them.

```r
ssh::ssh_exec_wait(sess, "mkdir '/home/r2/newlogs'")
# [1] 0
ssh::scp_upload(sess, files = basename(remote_files), to = "/home/r2/newlogs/")
# [100%] C:\Users\r2\...\dns.log
# [100%] C:\Users\r2\...\ping.log
# [100%] C:\Users\r2\...\status.log
# [1] "/home/r2/newlogs/"
```

(I find it odd that `scp_upload` is vectorized while `scp_download` is not. If this were on a shell/terminal, then each call to `scp` would need to connect, authenticate, copy, then disconnect, a bit inefficient; since we're using a saved `sess`ion, I *believe* (unverified) that there is little efficiency lost due to not vectorizing the R function ... though it is still *really easy* to vectorize it.)

Comment: In terms of locating the files from my server, what should I put after:
out <- ssh::ssh_exec_internal(sess, command = ___________)
because I am not receiving anything. Do I have to locate where the files are on my server and use that directory or what?

Comment: Did you read my example? It demonstrates one (of many) possibilities. You need to know the directory they're in, unless you really want to download the entire remote server's filesystem listing (which I do *not* recommend).

Comment: You might be able to get away with something like `"find ~ -type f -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.jpg'`, if the `~` shorthand for "my home directory" works in your ssh connection.

Comment: Is it possible to have it automatically just take the data from the server and immediately upload it to a website? Because I do in fact want ALL the data on the server to be displayed (eventually) on the website!

Comment: `"find / -type f"` will return all files. Because of that, though, you may do better with downloading a compressed tarball, uploading that one file, then `ssh_exec_wait(sess, "tar xzf myfile.tar.gz")`. If you aren't familiar with `tar` or `find` or other shell commands, then perhaps this isn't the best way for you to be doing this. Frankly, I don't think R offers any value here, I'd think `rsync` (shell command) would be far better/efficient. ... but you need to know shell commands for that.

Comment: BTW, it is highly likely (though not certain) that listing all files will list a lot of files that have absolutely nothing to do with what you want.

Comment: I suggest that before you go another step forward, you confirm that *"all files on site A"* is appropriate. In many places, this will include all DLLs, libraries, executables, logs, configuration files ... that your user has permissions to read.

Comment: Said differently: https://giphy.com/gifs/jeff-goldblum-jurassic-park-jurassicparkedit-mCClSS6xbi8us. (Caption: Ian Malcom from Jurassic Park saying *"Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they never stopped to think if they should."*)